# Where is the story of Yashoda's complaining not witnessing Krishna's marriages found?

Tags: krishna, venkateshwara, yashoda

There is a story in relation to Lord Balaji that mother Yashoda could not witness Krishna's marriages and when she was at death bed, she desired that she may witness Krishna's marriage at least in next incarnation.

The story says that Yashoda took birth as [Vakula Devi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vakula_Devi) and witnessed Lord Srinivasa's marriage.

Pleas relate the story in answer if the above one is not accurate.

What is the source of the story?